# anchor href attributes not resolving to target on web page

Tags: html

There web page in question can be found here - http://oneadvice.co.uk/about/

Please observe the following issue. In the right hand sidebar labelled "In This Section" there are 3 `<a>` elements that are not resolving to their respective targets:

```
<a href="/about#facts">Key Facts</a>
<a href="/about#regulation">Regulation</a>
<a href="/about#compliance">Compliance and Complaints</a>
```

On the web page are the targets that the href attribute should resolve to, namely `<h3>` elements. However they are not doing.

```
<h3 id="facts">Key Facts</h3>
<h3 id="regulation">Regulation</h3>
<h3 id="compliance">Compliance and Complaints</h3>
```

I consider this quite strange behaviour as the other `<a>` elements do resolve to the corresponding `<h3>` elements.

Is there something glaringly obvious I am missing? This is a strange bug and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/about`.

```
<a href="#facts">Key Facts</a>
<a href="#regulation">Regulation</a>
<a href="#compliance">Compliance and Complaints</a>
```

> The href attribute indicates the link target, either a URL or a URL
>   fragment. A URL fragment is a name preceded by a hash mark (#), which
>   specifies an internal target location (an ID) within the current
>   document

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)